# Elasticsearch NEST create case-insensitive index

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

How can I create an index in NEST which compares case-insensitive with TermQuery?

I tried following (and many similar approaches) but my TermQuery only returns case-sensitive matching results.

```
Client.CreateIndex("my_index", (c) => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(an => an
            .Analyzers(ans => ans
                .Custom("analyzer_keyword", cu => cu
                    .Tokenizer("keyword")
                    .Filters("lowercase")
                 )
                .Custom("analyzer_term", cu => cu
                    .Tokenizer("term")
                    .Filters("lowercase")
                 )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to do this with NEST but one thing I know - you have two options:

1. you can specify `default` analyzer

or

2. you need to **use** your `analyzer_keyword` and `analyzer_term` for your document's fields.

Because your code now only specifies some custom analyzers which are not used anywhere.

Take a look at [specifying an index time analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html#_specifying_an_index_time_analyzer):

> At index time, if no `analyzer` has been specified, it looks for an analyzer in the index settings called `default`. Failing that, it defaults to using the `standard` analyzer.

and [specifying a search time analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html#_specifying_a_search_time_analyzer):

> The analyzer to use to search a particular field is determined by looking for:
>
> - An `analyzer` specified in the query itself.
> - The `search_analyzer` mapping parameter.
> - The `analyzer` mapping parameter.
> - An analyzer in the index settings called `default_search`.
> - An analyzer in the index settings called `default`.
> - The `standard` analyzer.

Comment: Thank you very much! The hint with the default analyzer did the trick for me. But the second hint is also very useful to know for future requirements.

Comment: Great to hear that :)

Comment: With NEST: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-analyzers.html